# PDO query method with bindValue() seems not to be working

Tags: php, mysql, oop, data-binding, pdo

It never works. And when I do a var dump on the sql query I see that the question marks are still in it. Which means that the values have not been binded right?

I don't understand why it's not binding the values.

Can anybody help me out?

**PHP**

```
$ruleValue = "value1";
$input = "value2";
$inputValue = "value3";

$this->_db->query('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?', array($ruleValue, $input, $inputValue));
```

**Method**

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
        var_dump($this->_query);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**var_dump**

```
object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(27) "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?" }
```

Comment: You cannot bind table names and column names.  Further on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182910/php-pdo-bind-table-name

Comment: @vee  `=` in this `if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql))` really mean something in `if` statement?

Comment: @Stranger, the `=` in `if` statement to me is OP's desire to reduce one line of code, but it's valid. `_pdo->prepare()` if successful returns `PDOStatement` and `false` otherwise. It might also raise `PDOException`. Use of assignment `=` vs equality `==`  is your confusion, is my assumption correct? Use of `try...catch` around `prepare` and checking for `if (!$this->query)` might have been more readable?

Comment: @vee Yeah, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
$ruleValue = "value1";
$input = "value2";
$inputValue = "value3";

$this->_db->query('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?', array($ruleValue, $input, $inputValue)
```

4 lines
insecure
saves state -> a HUGE pitfall you dug for yourself
never works

regular PDO

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM value1 WHERE value2 = ?')
$stmt->execute([$value3]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

3 lines
secure
stateless
works

Conclusion: GET RID of this malicious function and use raw PDO

Comment: U say it's malicious, but how is it malicious exactly?

Comment: 1. As I said above, introducing state, you'll be in trouble as soon as you try a nested query. Class variable $stmt will be overwritten and your code screwed up. 2. Having table and field names as variables is a call for disaster.