# Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, oop, object, pdo

I do not know why it returns the `Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object` error because I am using the fetchAll method on the _sth object.

Does anybody know why it does this?

**FormValidator PHP**

```
$users = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM $ruleValue WHERE $input = ?", array($inputValue));
if($users->count()) {
    $this->addError($input, $rule);
}
```

**Method**

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_sth = $this->_dbh->prepare($sql);

    if($this->_sth = $this->_sth->execute($params)) {
        return $this->_sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: [**And again you're trying to use your erroneous function**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200937/pdo-query-method-with-bindvalue-seems-not-to-be-working), with same outcome.

Comment: Only why I am using it on a function is so that I don't have to repeat the same code over and over.

Comment: `execute()` returns a boolean.  It doesn't have a `fetchAll()` function.  Just do `if($this->_sth->execute($params)) {`.

Comment: there is not much code to repeat but there is a HUGE hole in security. you should **get rid of ALL the variables** in the query

Comment: `WHERE $input` here, for example

Comment: this time you almost nailed the function, I have to admit. And only query here goes to be unsafe. You should never use a single variable in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($this->_sth = $this->_sth->execute($params)) {
```

The single `=` is an assignment operator. `execute()` returns a boolean TRUE or FALSE, and you're assigning that to `$this->_sth`.

```
    return $this->_sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Neither TRUE nor FALSE is an object, and has no `fetchAll()` method.

The comment from @RocketHazmat is correct, you can test the return value of `execute()` *without* assigning it to _sth. Example:

```
if($this->_sth->execute($params)) {
    return $this->_sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said already, there are two HUGE flaws.

1. DO NOT introduce state in your class. Use local variables and return the result.
2. Ther should be **not a single variable in the query** ever.

DO NOT introduce state in

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $sth = $this->_dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($params);
    return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

is ALL you need.

Don't be lazy, write full query.

```
$user = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE param = ?", [$inputValue]);
if($user) {
    $this->addError($input, $rule);
}
```