# PDO SQL Query Error in Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello Im getting the following error when trying to update my database:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''1'' in 'where clause''

Im getting three variables via POST They are:

a) the Column I want to change

b) The new value for the column

c) the ID which row to change...

Im using PDO, this is my Query with param-binding and execution:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE `artists` SET `:spalte` = `:wert` WHERE  `id` = `:pk` ');
$stmt->bindParam(':spalte', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':wert', $value);
$stmt->bindParam(':pk', $pk);
$stmt->execute();
```

I hope someone will understand this error...

Best Regards

Dave

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477730/why-does-backticks-fails-in-pdo-query) for **Why does backticks fails in PDO query?**

Comment: You can only use prepared statement parameters for values, not field names.

Comment: Then how can I safely insert the variable as field name?

Comment: remove the backticks from  your keys in your query;  PDO behaves differently.   you can leave `artists` but remove them from (for example) `:spalte` and `:wert`

Comment: As a simple rule you can not bind the column and table name in prepared statement, and you are using backticks for the placeholder in value section this is also wrong.

Comment: also, define the variables before you do the update.  You can set them equal to each other in PHP

Comment: Removing the Backticks and using sprintf to insert the $name variable worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can only use prepared statement parameters for values, not field names. –  *Vatev*

Exactly, If you want to put fieldnames from variable then why don't you put that directly in your sql.

This should do the trick.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE `artists` SET `'.$name.'` = :wert WHERE  `id` = :pk ');
```

To sanitize column name you could use [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: That worked! Thank you!