# Executing prepared PDO statement gives "General error: 10 disk I/O error" (PHP)

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

```
            $sql = "REPLACE INTO `myTable` VALUES (:symbol1, :symbol1), (:symbol1, :symbol2)";
            $statement = $this->pdoObject->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array(':symbol1' => $symbol1, ':symbol2' => $symbol2));
```

The above throws a PDOException:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error

I don't see an error in the statement.

Comment: Isn't is a MySQL error?

Comment: **Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.**

Comment: "Isn't is a MySQL error?" - no, but a sqlite error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO - Bind table name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182910/php-pdo-bind-table-name)

Comment: @Saty: the statement does neither.

Comment: I am not binding the table name.

Comment: Unfortunately the PDO_sqlite extension doesn't return the extended error code as there are [26 different extended codes for I/O errors](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort_rollback.html) alone. Don't focus on PDO but on the sqlite error itself. There are several answers here on SO and dba.stackexchange.com for "sqlite disk I/o error" that address a range of possible causes. Could be as simple as having the "wrong" file permissions, as bad as your hdd failing or anything inbetween like e.g. the journal_mode.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the permissions of the database and making it read-and-writable by the user www-data seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Wow, still getting these errors afterall...

Comment: Have you tried a database that is ceated by the php script? Does the error only come up when the statement replaces a record (instead of inserting a new one)? Does the same happen with a plain INSERT statement? And an UPDATE statement? And a DELETE statement? SELECT works as expected?

Comment: I deleted the contents of the /tmp folder and also restarted the system. So far, the error has not returned.

Comment: Seems related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53090/occasional-disk-i-o-errors-in-sqlite