# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error on Laravel SQLite parse

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel-5

I have a case where I upload an SQLite DB to Laravel to be parsed for the data within. I am currently using Homestead for this project.

When I upload an SQLite db sized under a MB, all seems alright. As soon as I upload a DB that is 2MB I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error

What can be the trouble here? Is this a Homestead thing? The physical HD has plenty of space so it isn't a space problem. I've checked the permissions on the directory the file is being read from and the permissions are alright. Any ideas?

Comment: what is "Homestead"?

Comment: A VirtualBox environment for Laravel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear enough and I reasked it with more depth.

Comment: please just delete it

Comment: I'm having this problem too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33607983/470749 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53090/18098 seem related, but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: its because your sqlite is open somewhere else. Close all other connetion to sqlite and try