# Using PDO and Between

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok, I've got a quick question. I'm using PDO to communicated with a MySQL db. Using BETWEEN with two dates as the variable is easy:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM awesome WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end");
```

What I don't think is easy is when I have one date and two columns. This doesn't work, no matter how loudly I cuss:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM awesome WHERE :one_date BETWEEN start_col AND end_col");
```

Is there a way to use BETWEEN without reverting to something awful like...?

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM awesome WHERE '$one_date' BETWEEN start_col AND end_col");
```

Or should I just stick to not using BETWEEN in this case?

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM awesome WHERE start_col<=:one_date1 AND end_col>=:one_date2")
```

Thanks!

Comment: well for one thing, `WHERE :one_date` you can't do that. You can't bind a column. So you can stop cussin' about it, now you know ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182910/php-pdo-bind-table-name

Comment: so, you want to check if two columns match the criteria, is that what your question is about?

Comment: @ me if you need me. Moving on.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>BETWEEN only works with one column and two values.</strike>

But your last approach should work. That's at least the way to go

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM awesome" .
    " WHERE start_col <= :one_date1 AND end_col >= :one_date2"
);
```

When using named parameters you should also be able to use the same name twice and only need to bind once.

**Update**

Well, just tested it and worked for me with " WHERE 'value' between col1 and col2". (tested postgres with datetime, mysql with integer)

Comment: thanks. I was actually aware that using a value followed by between works. But when I've tried getting that to work as a prepared statement, it fails. Maybe it's my PDO class?

Comment: @jonlink I've currently only a test environment with postgres, but this works with PDO and bindValue() as well. If it doesn't work for you, do you get any errors (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php / ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)