# use a table name that is equal or similar to variable captured in form to do query

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I have a variable $city and it passes a value from the submit form as "New York" when this happens, I want to do a query in a table name that matches the $city value. in this case New York.

The table name would be New_York

Form page
For example:  What city do you need?: $city 
Submit

Results page

```
$city=$_POST['city'];
$sql = $db->query(Select * from $city);
```

(where $city should be the name of the table)

How do I accomplish this?

Keep in mind my city list has names that use spaces whereas table names cant.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of appallingly bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to replace spaces with underscores using str_replace

```
$city = str_replace(' ', '_',$_POST['city']);
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM {$city}");
```

***please note this code is prone to sql attacks*

Comment: would you recommend I use a new variable name as I do "print" the city name in a paragraph in the page?

Comment: Yes otherwise you will be having _ in your paragraph

Comment: Thank you and to make reference to this new $citytbl in the query I just use the variable name directly or do I have to use special characters around it?

Comment: what would be the pdo version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182910/php-pdo-bind-table-name   Please read