# Laravel 5.5 and DB::raw can't execute query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to execute a query with `DB::raw` but it seems not working at all.
For some reason, Laravel does not execute the bindings, and the query fails. I have tried a lot of queries, events, and even a simple one doesn't work.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$query = 'select id from :my_table';

$results = DB::select(
    DB::raw($query),
    [
        'my_table' => 'advertisement__rentadvertisements',
    ]
);

dd($results);
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?' at line 1 (SQL: select id from :my_table)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're doing the above as a raw query and not using the methods on the query builder?

Comment: That's not my final query, is just an example to show that event that easy query do not work

Comment: If you can please don't just provide a simplified version of what you're trying to achieve as it means that you will usually not get the help/advise that you're after. Can you add the code you actually have to your question and also, if you can, just provide a quick overview of what you're trying to achieve and why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182910/php-pdo-bind-table-name), you can't just replace table names or columns.

Unless you've simplified your example and there is more going on than you've mentioned I would suggest just using the query builder:

```
DB::table('advertisement__rentadvertisements')->get('id')
```

Comment: Thanks Ross, the problem was the table name, I used a placeholder for it. If I remove it, the query works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, try remove the `:` in your `$query` and you should be fine, and also your statement needs an condition like `select * from table_name where id = ?`

Answer (score 0):

Your binding syntax seems to be the issue. A semicolon is missing in your array:

```php
$query = "select id from :my_table";

$results = DB::select(
    DB::raw($query),
    [
        ':my_table' => 'advertisement__rentadvertisements',
    ]
);
```

The error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 (SQL: select id from :my_table)"
```

is indicating that `:my_table` within your query is not replaced by `advertisement__rentadvertisements`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just replace table names or columns.

See more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects

Change:

```
$query = 'select id from :my_table';

$results = DB::select(
    DB::raw($query),
    [
        'my_table' => 'advertisement__rentadvertisements',
    ]
);
```

to:

```
$results = DB::table('advertisement__rentadvertisements')->select('id')->get();
```

Hope it will help you.