# FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: php, sql, nginx

1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dataInjections' LIKE 'type'' at line 1 in /.../.../.../restapi.php:174

```
private function CheckUpdates()
{
    if(!$this->columnExists('dataInjections','type'))
    {
        $connection = self::Connection();
        $statement = $connection->prepare("ALTER TABLE `dataInjections` ADD `type` INT(0) NOT NULL AFTER `icon`");  
        $count = $statement->execute();
    }
}

private function columnExists($tblName, $clmnName)
{
    $connection = self::Connection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ? LIKE ?");    
    $count = $statement->execute([$tblName, $clmnName]);
    if ( $count != 0 )
        return true;
    return false;
}

private function tableExists($tblName)
{
    $connection = self::Connection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = ?");    
    $statement->execute([$tblName]);
    $tableCount = $statement->fetchColumn();
    if ( $tableCount != 0 )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Cannot bind table or column names. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15182926/7644018

Comment: @PaulT. Hello, I have looked into the issue but still can't solve it.